# ArrayList content to JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jlabel

If i have an ArrayList of type Integer, containing numbers like 1,3,4,9,10 etc... How can i display those on a JLabel, not the sum, but all the numbers in a sequence.

So the JLabel would display, in this case: 134910

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: Thank you all, ofcourse i should have thought about append. Anyways, thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Integer i : list) {
    sb.append(i == null ? "" : i.toString());
}
lbl.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Yeah, checking for null, since these are objects.  I figured an empty string might be preferable to the text "null". :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String fromListToString(List<Integer> input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer num : input) {
        sb.append(num);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(9);
    list.add(10);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(fromListToString(list)));
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList( 1, 3, 5, 7 );

    StringBuilder joined = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer number : list) {
        joined.append( number );
    }
    new JLabel().setText( joined.toString() );
```

Comment: Or even better: `ArrayList<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7);`

Comment: Or even better: `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7);`

Comment: Thanks, it really looks better this way.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Lang to the rescue (again) with [StringUtils.join()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29) (in different flavours).

Answer (score 0):

You start with an empty string (or StringBuilder). Then you iterate through the items of the list, adding each item to the string. Then you set the string as the JLabel's text.